# How to change the flags in the tcp header of a packet in NS-2?

Tags: c, tcp, tcl, ns2, ns-3

I'm trying to change the ECN mark in the tcp header of a specific packet in NS-2 but could not find the way.
Is there anyone who can give me a hand? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: Hi Donal Fellows, I found it today in ns2.35/tcp/tcp-full.cc , line 874. Thanks for asking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it in ns2.35/tcp/tcp-full.cc , line 874. Below is the code that marks ECN(or we can say ECE here).

```
if (ecn_ && ect_ && recent_ce_ ) { 
    // This is needed here for the ACK in a SYN, SYN/ACK, ACK
    // sequence.
    pflags |= TH_ECE;
}
```